# SQL converting two address column into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, unpivot

I have a table

[image]

In result I am expecting only two columns Name and address ,for add1 and aad2 if they are similar i want to only show them once in address and for different aad1 and add2 I want to show them twice in two different rows
I am expecting this output

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to unpivot using `cross apply`.  In your case, you can use logic like this:

```
select t.name, v.add
from t cross apply
     (values (1, add1), (2, add2)) v(n, add)
where n = 1 or (n = 2 and t.add1 <> t.add2);
```

That is, always take the first address.  Take the second when it is different from the first.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle database and sql-server, union operator remove duplicate rows

```sql
select name, add1 as address from mytable
union
select name, add2 from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

A portable approach uses `union all` to unpivot the columns to rows and eliminate the duplicates:

```
select name, add1 as add from mytable
union all select name, add2 from mytable where add2 <> add1
```

Depending on your database, there may be a better option available. A typical solution is a lateral join - but the syntax highly depend on the database (and not all of them implement that feature).

---

**Edit**: in SQL Server:

```
select t.name, a.add
from mytable t
cross apply (values (add1), (case when add1 <> add2 then add2 end)) a(add)
where a.add is not null
```

Comment: dude this worked i dont know how but it did thanks!!

Comment: Welcome @shubham. Since you tagged your question SQL Server finally, I added a (better) solution for that database.

Comment: sorry for late response new on stack overflow